# How to migrate to Gatling 2.2 from 2.1.7

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm not really good with Scala and I really want to love Gatling, but lack of documentation makes it really difficult.
Here is the problem that I've encountered after trying to migrate to 2.2.0 version from 2.1.7:

- **global** - now requires GatlingConfiguration for some reason, could someone provide example of how to use it with latest version?
- **throttling** - now should be added via some sort of ThrottlingSteps -as before, could someone give me example how to use it correctly?

Worst part of this madness is that on official Gatling website [migration article](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/migration_guides/2.1-to-2.2.html) doesn't cover this part and [official documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/general/assertions.html?highlight=assertions) is obsolete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: Gatling founder here

No, documentation is perfectly up-to-date and issues are most likely on your side.

First, all the pieces of code in our documentation are actually real classes that gets compiled as part of our build process before their source code is getting pasted into the documentation.

Then, we also have some internal classes stored in the test sources to double check that everything compiles fine, such as `HttpCompileTest` that uses both [assertions](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-http/src/test/scala/io/gatling/http/HttpCompileTest.scala#L269-L279) and [throttling](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-http/src/test/scala/io/gatling/http/HttpCompileTest.scala#L280).

Finally, our public layer is the DSL, and only the DSL. So we only document DSL changes, not implementation ones.

Either you're missing Gatling standard imports (such as `import io.gatling.core.Predef._`), or have transformed them into smaller imports so you end up importing DSL implementations. Those implementations have indeed changed in Gatling 2.2 but then, you're not supposed to see them for normal usage.

Or, you've build your own DSL on top of ours, so you indeed use our implementations. But then, you're only supposed to do that if you're sufficiently proficient with Scala as you're not sticking to our public layer: the DSL.

Comment: You was right, probably should've checked git example before asking, my bad. Thank you!